# crontab doesn't work corectly

Tags: linux-mint, cron, notifications

I want to make some notification to user every day at the same time:

> any_hour:50

And I wrote to `crontab -e`:

> 50 * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/notify-send -i /home/nazar/Pictures/icons/download_manager.png "Break" "Make a break for 10 min"

When I run it from console:

> notify-send -i /home/nazar/Pictures/icons/download_manager.png "Break" "Make a break for 10 min"

I have desired result:

[image]

But when I working at PC I don't have this output at desired time.

***Any suggestion?***

**UPDATE:**

I updated cron job to:

> 50 * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/notify-send -i /home/nazar/Pictures/icons/download_manager.png "Work Break" "Make a break for 10 min, please!" 2>&1 | tee -a cron.out

After executing it file was created but it is empty.

I tried to update my cron job as follows:

```
00 13 * * *  /home/nazar/Documents/scripts/lunch_break_job.sh
50 *  * * *  /home/nazar/Documents/scripts/pc_break.sh

# just cron test
*/1  *  * * *  /home/nazar/Documents/scripts/cron_job_test.sh
```

and `cron_job_test.sh` looks:

```
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=0.0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/matrix/.Xauthority

if [ -r "$HOME/.dbus/Xdbus" ]; then
  . "$HOME/.dbus/Xdbus"
fi

/usr/bin/notify-send "hello"
```

when I run this script from terminal:

> ./cron_job_test.sh

I get notification correctly.
But crontab doesn't run this script every minute.

Why does this happen?
***And how to resolve execution of this cron job?***

Comment: This is probably because setting DISPLAY isn't enough; your X server must be rejecting the connection. Are you able to receive error output from cron jobs (it sends e-mail)? That would allow use to better understand what is going on. Otherwise, append `2>&1 | tee -a cron.out` to your job to create a log file.

Comment: @dhag can you explain more about logging cron? have should look my updated cron job?

Comment: As I said, add `2>&1 | tee -a cron.out` to the end of your cron job, and, after it runs, look in file `cron.out`.

Comment: @dhag I updated question.

Comment: The `cron_job_test.sh` you pasted is missing the closing `"` (last line). Is this just a copy & paste error? (Please [edit] your question and fix it if so.)

Comment: @derobert it is just copy/paste trouble. script works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to edit the crontab of that particular user i.e.

```
su -l nazar
crontab -e
```

Comment: can you explain more? I didn't get what your answer means.

Comment: That would only be useful if we had reason to believe the asker is running commands as root, which seems to me an unreasonable assumption.

Comment: @dhag Do you mean to run `sudo crontab -e`?

Comment: No, I mean that this answer seems completely irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: Well he refers to "the user", unless he is referring to himself in the third person it's perfectly logical to assume that he *might* be trying to edit his own crontab given that he makes no mention of running it under a another user. But thinking about it, shouldn't his above syntax be: 50 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/bin/notify-send -i /home/nazar/Pictures/icons/download_manager.png "Break" "Make a break for 10 min"

Comment: @dcrdev do you mean add `&&`?

Comment: I see where your assumption comes from, @dcrdev, that makes some sense. The `VAR=value command` form should be valid syntax.